# How to install an older version of Hex?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, hex-pm

If I run `mix local.hex`, I'd get the latest version of Hex. How can I:

- list available versions;
- install an older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install an older version of hex, use `mix hex.install`. See `mix help hex.install`:

> mix hex.install
>
> Manually installs specific Hex version.
>
> ```
> mix hex.install VERSION
> ```

I don't know how to list the available hex versions from the command line, but the [changelog on GitHub](https://github.com/hexpm/hex/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) should be useful.